# Mybatis annotations with Typehandlers Bad grammar error

Tags: annotations, mybatis, typehandler

How to use Mybatis annotaions with type handlers.
And where we will get the best source to learn the content

Getting bad grammer while using annotaion with mybatis

Comment: To get help you need to include the code you use and the exception with error message you get.

Comment: @Select(""
   + "#{ orders, mode=OUT, jdbcType=ARRAY, jdbcTypeName=GET_TAB, typeHandler=com.fmrco.dao.mybatis.GetOrderTypeHandler  } = call"
   + " aip_order_pkg.get_order("
   + "#{ order_ids, mode=IN,jdbcType=ARRAY, jdbcTypeName=ID_TAB, typeHandler=com.order.dao.mybatis.IdTableTypeHandler})")
   @Options(statementType = StatementType.CALLABLE)

Comment: Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement\n\n; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Comment: Could you provide a small reproduce project?